# Why i Can't get birthday from facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

Here is my code.I am getting email fb id gender name but not birthday.
What is wrong with my code. I am searching from 3 days and try many times.

```
  showHashKey(getActivity());
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        tv_facebook = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv_facebook);
        Typeface arialblack_typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                "arial_black.ttf");
        tv_facebook.setTypeface(arialblack_typeface);
        tv_facebook.setTextSize(40);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.inear_Layout);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // login successful
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Main Activity in LoginResult on success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                      //  final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest
                                (loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                        // Application code
                                        Log.v("MAinFrgment", response.toString());
                                        System.out.println("Check: " + response.toString());
                                        try {
                                            String id = object.getString("id");
                                            String name = object.getString("name");
                                            String email = object.getString("email");
                                            String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                            String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                            System.out.println(id + ", " + name + ", " + email + ", " + gender + ", " + birthday);
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // login cancelled
                        Log.e("OnCancel ","Oncancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // login error
                        Log.e("OnCancel ","Error" +exception);
                    }
                });
        return rootview;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.inear_Layout:
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile,user_friends,user_birthday,user_about_me,email,basic_info"));

               /* FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                Personal_Detail personal_detail = new Personal_Detail();

                ft.replace(R.id.mainContainer,personal_detail);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();*/

                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public static void showHashKey(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "google_play.flightdataui", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.i("KeyHash:",
                        Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                // String abc = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                // Base64.DEFAULT);
                // System.out.println(abc);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the Response .

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"1488687718111904","gender":"male","email":"nafees4343@gmail.com","name":"Haider Rana"}, error: null}
```

Q) How can i get user Birthday 1?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-public_profile. That is all you get by default. You will need extra permissions. This requires verification of your app by facebook. Check the link for things that requires review and things that do not.

Comment: So my code is correct or not?

Comment: you get the response so its working. Read the link posted for more information. By default you won't get birthday. You need to code and provide your apk to facebook for a review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(WelcomeActivity1.this, (Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends","user_birthday","user_about_me","email")));
```

**In oncreate method try using this code:**

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
     @Override
      public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
      Log.d("tag","FF fb onSuccess");
      GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
         try {
               String[] splited ;
               JSONObject obj =  object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data");

                                  if (object.has("birthday"))
                                  {
                                     Birthday =  object.getString("birthday");
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      Birthday = "";
                                  }



                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,birthday,picture,email,gender");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("tag","fb onCancel");
                     // App code
                }



    @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.d("tag","fb onError");
                     // App code   
                }
    });
```

Note: Also, try with different FB account , because in some FB account user may not shared their Birthday date to others